# Android milliseconds with zone offset to Date

Tags: android, datetime

I current have (from server) a date stamp returned as ticks (.NET Date).

In general I managed to convert the above by subtracting by 10000 to produce secs and offset accordingly to get EPOC ms.

Now, the issue is that the ms passed from server include the zone offset and what I needed to do is get a TimeZone object for the zone (always the same) and subtract the ms offset (depending on DST) from the original value to produce a new object to properly get a Date.

Any better way of doing this without so many conversion?

```
private static long netEpocTicksConv = 621355968000000000L;
public static Date dateTimeLongToDate(long ticks) {
    TimeZone greeceTz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Athens");
    Calendar cal0 = new GregorianCalendar(greeceTz); 

    long time = (ticks - netEpocTicksConv)/ 10000;
    time -= greeceTz.getOffset(time);
    cal0.setTimeInMillis(time);

    Date res = cal0.getTime();

    return res; 
}
```

Comment: "Now, the issue is that the ms passed from server include the zone offset" - can this be changed? It would make a lot more sense for it to return a UTC timestamp, I suspect.

Comment: I wouldn't post the question otherwise ;)

Comment: Fundamentally, there's a problem - if the server is effectively giving you a local date/time, then it may be ambiguous - the same local date/time occurs twice during the daylight saving transition backwards.

Comment: The server will ALWAYS give me MS in Greece zone, but I need to convert them to a Date format for processing and display. There is no ambiguity as local device time/zone is ignored.

Comment: No, you don't understand. If it's giving you the *local* time in Greece, that can be ambiguous. Consider the local time of Sunday, October 27, 2013, 3.30am in Athens. What's the offset then? That date/time occurs twice, as the clocks go back at 4am.

Comment: Sorry I do understand that a TimeZone instance will give me the DST and offset for a given time in UTC spectrum. But I cant say I know everything either. If there is no way of creating a GregorianCalendar or Date based on the milliseconds for a given zone and time I suppose a "no can do" might fit the bill. I know the code above has issues close to DST changes and the like. :-)

Comment: The point is that you haven't *got* the given time in UTC. You've got the *local* time in Greece. Otherwise you wouldn't need to adjust for the offset, would you? *If* you're okay with it giving dodgy answers near DST transitions, the code you've got probably works - but you don't need to create a `Calendar`. I'll post code to demonstrate what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code which doesn't quite do the right thing near DST transitions:

```
private static final long DOTNET_TICKS_AT_UNIX_EPOCH = 621355968000000000L;
private static final TimeZone GREECE = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Athens");

public static Date dateTimeLongToDate(long ticks) {

    long localMillis = (ticks - DOTNET_TICKS_AT_UNIX_EPOCH) / 10000L;

    // Note: this does the wrong thing near DST transitions
    long offset = GREECE.getOffset(localMillis - GREECE.getRawOffset());
    long utcMillis = localMillis - offset;
    return new Date(utcMillis);
}
```

There's no need to use a `Calendar` here.

You *can* get it to be accurate around DST transitions unless it's actually ambiguous, in which case you could make it either always return the earlier version or always return the later version. It's fiddly to do that, but it can be done.

By subtracting the offset for standard time, we're already reducing the amount of time during which it will be incorrect. Basically this code now says, "Subtract the standard time (no daylight savings) offset from the local time, to get an approximation to the UTC time. Now work out the offset at that UTC time."

Comment: Considering the fact that the DST offset is included in the ticks provided, you are correct that this is an unsolvable solution but your suggestion (as per my original code), does near-solve the issue. The only reason I used calendar is due to the fact that the local time zone may not be Athens/Greece. Thanks!

Comment: @George: Which local time zone? The server one? Change the GREECE part of my code. The local one on the machine running the Java code? That's irrelevant. In neither case do you need a Calendar object.